# ORM does not bring all the fields of a custom model of users

Tags: python, django, forms, orm, user-controls

I am trying to get a user that I have saved with a custom model as follows:

```
TblUsers.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
```

But this only brings up the "email" field of my record, however I have many more fields in my custom model
What brings me:

```
<QuerySet [<TblUsuarios: juan@juan.com>]>
```

My custom model:

```
class TblUsers(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField("email address", unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    phone= models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, null=True)
    photo= models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image, default = '/')

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=(['username'])
    objects = UserManager()
    class Meta:
        managed=True
        db_table = 'tbl_users'
```

The manager class of my custom user:

```
class UserManager(UserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create a user
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_("The email must have info"))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create a super user
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_active", True)

        if extra_fields.get("is_staff") is not True:
            raise ValueError(_("The superuser should have is_staff=True."))
        if extra_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
            raise ValueError(_("The superuser should have is_superuser=True."))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

I have tried to get all the information from the table with:

```
TblUsers.objects.all()
```

But this has had the same result, it only fetches the "email" field from all the records

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand record only has 'email' value.

your ORM should get all User information.

Did means QuerySet result shows email?

```
<QuerySet [<TblUsuarios: juan@juan.com>]>
```

if your User Model class has this method

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.email
```

your UserModel instance will show email value.
[see this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/instances/#str)

have you tried this?

```
TblUsers.obejcts.values()
```

then can you find User informations?

if found it Your model and ORM is ok.